# How to migrate data from OUD 11g to OUD 12c

Tags: oracle, oim, oam

We are migrating from 11g to 12c. We have installed 12c (OIM, OAM, OUD). What is the best way forward for migrating user data because OIM contains user data with encrypted password ?

Comment: I personally haven't tried the following, but maybe you can prove it's working or not http://avijit-sengupta.blogspot.com/2017/05/decrypt-users-password-in-oim-11gr2-ps3.html, check first comment to the post. I think it might be a way to capture existing passwords

Answer (score 0):

First export all your data in a ldif file using export-ldif command, then make sure you copy all existing schemas (especialy if you have custom ones) to the new server and finnaly use dsconfig option allow-pre-encoded-password in your default password schema, the command would look like this:

```
./dsconfig -h localhost -p 4444 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w "passwd" -X -n set-password-policy-prop –policy-name "Default Password Policy" –advanced –set allow-pre-encoded-passwords:true –trustAll
```

And then you can import your data ldif, using import-ldif command.